# When I restart Ubuntu 19.04 it is asking to complete setup process

Tags: 19.04, restart, user-management

When I restart my system then it asks me to complete the setup process, like choose the language, create user, keyboard layout. But I already have users.

To come out of this process, I have to force restart my system using the power button. Since my system taking around 5 minutes to restart, it is wasting time to restart the laptop twice. For reference see the following screenshots. 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have to login first before the dialogs appear? If you complete the dialogs, are they being presented again the next time?

Comment: I am using the system for 3 months. It has user working fine. But sometimes when I restart the application it appears. And after completing the process a new user will be created and available during next boot.